# Opinion on website

Tags: sound-design, sound-effects, synthesis

Hi

I would like to comment on my website featuring sound design, sound effects and analog syntehesis tutorials. You can also see my works on the site.
Any and all comments welcome.
[link text](http://knobz.net)

a polish version for those interested:
[link text](http://knobz.pl)

Answer (score 1):

Here is my opinion:

You didn't post a link to this site in your links section!

Otherwise, good design and layout.

Answer (score 0):

As an RSS junkie, I can say that having a feed would be a great idea.  Especially if you plan to do regular updates.

I don't know how you would implement something like this, but a user input section where people can submit their own ideas would be cool too.

The concept is fantastic though.  I love learning how other people do their stuff.

Comment: RSS added

Also update: http://knobz.net/abandoned5.html